# Liquibase generateChangeLog succeeds but changelog is empty?

Tags: mariadb, liquibase

I just downloaded Liquibase 3.6.2, added the MariaDB driver and ran this command:

```
liquibase --url jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/db --changeLogFile changeLogFile.txt --username XXX --password xxx --diffTypes="data" generateChangeLog
Starting Liquibase at Mon, 17 Dec 2018 16:15:16 CET (version 3.6.2 built at 2018-07-03 11:28:09)
Liquibase command 'generateChangeLog' was executed successfully.
```

After that the file changeLogFile.txt exists in the current directory but is empty. The database however contained 11 empty tables. I would have expected some XML frame plus create table statements.

What should I do differently?

Comment: Update: It seems the file extension matters. I changed the output filename to changeLogFile.xml. Now at least I have the XML frame.
But still no changeset, no create table statement or anything else.

Comment: Update: Knowing the output file name matters I went through the other options I used and removed --diffTypes="data". Now I get the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with --diffTypes="data" you limit the export to data only. DDL xml will not be created.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to modify verbosity via --logLevel=debug ?